# Ubuntu 19.10 Using Laser Jet Pro M402n Jobs Held Even After Being Released

Tags: printing, hp, hplip

As per the title. I'm running the latest Ubuntu 19.10, and I have the standard hplip packages installed. I was able to configure my printer on the network so that I can ping it. Additionally, at times, jobs do go through.

However, they do not got through in a reliable manner. There's no way on the current HP Device Manager UI to release the jobs. They are just marked as "On hold" in the status bar.

But I can release them using CUPS in a browser with the standard localhost:631.

My question is, how do I get the jobs to print reliably so they are never held?

Please don't tell me to: turn it off and on nor to re-install nor anything else that's trial and error.

I'd like to know precisely why this is an issue, and how to fix it.

I'm willing to try any and all diagnostic commands and to print the results. Also, lmk if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

I had configured two separate printers for the same printer, and the default one was wrong. So CUPS was getting confused.

The solution was to find the proper printer by trial and error. In the print menu, I picked the non-default printer. This printed right away.

Then, I just had to merely delete the second printer using CUPS at localhost:631 in a web browser.

NOTE: When adding the printer, I followed these instructions: [“No suitable Destination Host found by cups-browsed”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128164/no-suitable-destination-host-found-by-cups-browsed) as I had the same error: ‘Idle - “No suitable Destination Host found by cups-browsed”’