# Printer Idle - No suitable destination host found by cups-browsed

Tags: apt, package-management, printing, mate

Printer Idle - No suitable destination host found by cups-browsed. Ubuntu 20.04. The [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1128869/) to "No suitable Destination Host found by cups-browsed" recommends `sudo apt-get purge --autoremove cups-browsed` .  When I do that, I get the following results:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  cups-browsed* libfprint-2-tod1* libquazip5-1* ubuntu-mate-core*
  ubuntu-mate-desktop*
```

I definitely need MATE and the removal of cups-browsed seems to force the removal of MATE.  Is there another workaround? May I remove cups-browsed and nothing else? The printer was working on the initial installation of 20.04, but one or more of the security upgrades seem to have caused a software failure. The printer is a Brother DCP-L2540DW series, driverless, cups-filters 1.27.4.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot purge cups-browsed because of dependency problems, you can stop it functioning with

```
systemctl mask cups-browsed
```

There is another way, but let's see how you go on with that.

Comment: Toggle it with `systemctl unmask` and `systemctl unmask` in case Yasha doesn't use the MATE desktop environment all the time.

Comment: sudo systemctl mask cups-browsed
[sudo] password for [redacted]: 
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/cups-browsed.service → /dev/null.      Hence, if one simply creates as root a symlink from any /etc/systemd/system/foobar.service to /dev/null foobar will be temporarily disabled?  Is this permanent after reboots?  What after upgrades?  I attempt to keep all systems current with respect to security fixes.

Comment: @Zanna.  Thank you for the modifications as you know the style and content that these Ubuntu support lists require.  It would be very useful if there were a style guide (the Ubuntu list equivalent of the style guides for professional journals, but clearly not as comprehensive) and instructions how to use the embedded editor to include URLs and the various highlighting/formatting conventions this list requires.  The editor is not LibreOffice, not vim, etc. Take care.  Stay safe.

Comment: The point of masking is that it survives a reboot and, I imagine, upgrades. You didn't say whether the command worked to solve your initial issue.

Comment: @brian_p I posted an answer -- your solution seems to be necessary but not sufficient.  Does anyone check that the proposed solutions actually work?  The first solution for an earlier release showed an apt removal that would have destroyed MATE.  Take care.  Stay safe.

Comment: Your OP was about getting "No suitable destination host found by cups-browsed". Masking cups-browsed is completely sufficient to eliminate getting this message because cups-browsed is not running. I imagine you observe this to be the case. You ask:"Does anyone check that the proposed solutions actually work?" Do you think we make things up?

Answer (score 0):

The removal of `cups-browsed` requires the removal of MATE in 20.04.1 LTS.

The command [given by brian_p](https://askubuntu.com/a/1288287/527764), `sudo systemctl mask cups-browsed` is step 1.

However, the software connection to the printer still exists and it will not print.

One then adds a new printer; in my case as the printer is accessed through my local IEEE 802.11 "wifi" network. This is a printer listed under **Network** during the **Add printer** dialog using the **Printer configuration** GUI under MATE control center (something similar from other window environments, as well as a CLI command -- someone else can supply these methods).

During the add printer dialog, there is also an option to print a test page -- if that works, one is done.