# total beginner solving “No suitable Destination Host found by cups-browsed”

Tags: printing

So I'm facing the “No suitable Destination Host found by cups-browsed” problem while trying to print. I already know that what I need to do is write "systemctl restart cups-browsed" and the problem will be solved... but I have clue where I should do it...

I know nothing about computers, but I managed to install this ubuntu system by my own (which is really a lot to me).
So I would be really happy and thankful if someone could help me how to solve this problem, but with baby steps.

Here is the previous topic, with people debating this issue [“No suitable Destination Host found by cups-browsed”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128164/no-suitable-destination-host-found-by-cups-browsed)

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Please open a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+t. Type in:

```
sudo systemctl restart cups-browsed
```

We must use sudo because stopping, starting and restarting system services is reserved for privileged users.

Press Enter. You will be asked for the sudo password. It will not be echoed back and not even **** for security reasons. Just type it in and press Enter again to supply the password.